# RSiteCatalyst number of rows top and start

Tags: r

I am using the API to connect to adobe analytics and i am struggling to understand the number of rows that i can have in each call.
For each of my calls i want to retrieve the first 100 lines then loop until i have all the data i want.
The paremeters top and start works fine if i have only one element but when i put two elements i have a number of rows that differs from what i want.

Example >

```
date.from <- "2015-06-20"
date.to <- "2015-06-20"
reportsuite.id <- "***"
metrics <- c("pageviews")
elements <- c("evar11")
top <- 30
start <- 1
report.data <- QueueTrended(reportsuite.id, date.from, date.to, metrics,   top=top , start=start, elements , date.granularity = "year" )
```

This gives me 30 lines starting from the first one.

But if i put two elements like this :

```
elements <- c("evar11","prop28")
```

Than my number of rows goes to 298 instead of 30.

Can someone explain me how to do to have the top 30 lines starting from the 1 using two elements.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible in the RSiteCatalyst package, but it is identified as a future enhancement.

https://github.com/randyzwitch/RSiteCatalyst/issues/137